# How to clear all cache in browser using ASP.net(C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dojo, browser-cache

I tried to use this code for clear cache but It not working with Google Chrome.
I need to clear all cache in browser or clear all website cache (not only one page)
Ps: Most of code using widget DOJO javascript that why I need to clear all cache.

```
List<string> keys = new List<string>();
// retrieve application Cache enumerator
IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = Cache.GetEnumerator();
// copy all keys that currently exist in Cache
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
  keys.Add(enumerator.Key.ToString());
}
// delete every key from cache
for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
{
  Cache.Remove(keys[i]);
}
HttpRuntime.Close();
```

Thank you for every answers.

Comment: I don't think you can remove cache of the browser. It will very browser to browser. But you can set cache time for your resources of you application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this to clear all cache of the browser

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
```

You can also refer: [Making sure a web page is not cached, across all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)